# Reading a P6 binary ppm file

Tags: c, struct, binaryfiles, ppm

So ive already read a number of the questions that relate to this but none of them have solved my problem. Im currently attempting to read in a P6 ppm file (Its a binary file). My current code is

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct pixel {
    char red;
    char green;
    char blue;
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    char type[3];
    int numRow, numCol, maxNum;
    FILE *oldFile, *newFile;
    struct pixel currentPixel;
    char buffer[5];

    oldFile = fopen(argv[1], "rb");
    if(oldFile == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file %s for reading in binary", argv[1]);
        return 0;
    }
    fscanf(oldFile, "%2s", type);
    type[2] = '\0';
    if(strcmp(type, "P6") != 0) {  //Make sure we have a P6 file
        printf("This file is not of type P6");
        return 0;
    }

    newFile = fopen(argv[2], "wb");
    fprintf(newFile, "%s\n", type);
    /*Read number of columns
    rows and
    The max number that can represent a colour*/
    fscanf(oldFile, "%d", &numCol);
    fscanf(oldFile, "%d", &numRow);
    fscanf(oldFile, "%d", &maxNum);
    /*Print the information to newFile*/
    fprintf(newFile, "%d %d\n", numCol, numRow);
    fprintf(newFile, "%d\n", maxNum);
    fseek(oldFile, 1, SEEK_CUR);

    fread(&currentPixel, sizeof(struct pixel), 1, oldFile);
    printf("%c %c %c", currentPixel.red, currentPixel.green, currentPixel.blue);

    fclose(newFile);
    fclose(oldFile);
    return 0;
}
```

So the  beginning works and my newFile contains the lines P6, 3 3, and 255. I then try to read in the actual pixels with the `fread` line. This is where it fails and im not sure why. It currently prints out two question marks inside of a diamond. I am currently only trying to read in the first three numbers which make up one pixel (one red component one green and one blue).

I also have a P3 file of the same picture and the P3 file looks like:

```
 P3

3 3

255

  0 255 255   0   0   0   0   0 255

255   0 255 100 100 100 255   0   0

255 255   0 255 255 255   0 255   0
```

So the binary file should be set up like this but just in binary format. When i type in

> od -c binaryImage.ppm

I get

```
0000000   P   6  \n   3       3  \n   2   5   5  \n  \0 377 377  \0  \0
0000020  \0  \0  \0 377 377  \0 377   X   X   X 377  \0  \0 377 377  \0
0000040 377 377 377  \0 377  \0
0000046
```

Im not sure why my fread function is not working.Not sure if relevant but i am compiling on Linux Ubuntu with

> gcc -Wall rotate.c -o rotate

Comment: @WeatherVane The first three lines are regular text. Reading those with `fscanf` works fine but after that we need to read using `fread` since the rest of the file is written in binary

Comment: Why are you printing RGB values as characters (%c) instead as numbers (%d)? That's the reason you get strange symbols in the output.

Comment: @BrunoBellucci Thats a good question. I changed my code so instead of red, green and blue being char i made them int's. It now prints out `16776960 0 -16711681`

Comment: No. Your pixel values should be char, but you need print them as integers.

Comment: @BrunoBellucci That prints out `0 -1 -1`

Comment: Use `unsigned char` to cover the 0-255 range.

Comment: As @WumpusQ.Wumbley said, use `unsigned char` or do a `cast` when using the value. I updated the answer with more details.

Comment: @BrunoBellucci Okay so that works thank you very much for your help. Is there any way you could give me a quick explanatioon of why it works? Im a little bit confused. Nevermind just saw your answer :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are printing RGB values as characters instead as numbers. Keep them as `unsigned char` (because they have values between [0-255]) in the structure, but use `%d` when printing. You should use `printf` as follows:

```
printf("%d %d %d", currentPixel.red, currentPixel.green, currentPixel.blue);
```

Also I recommend do not use a structure to read the RGB values because the compiler will probably add a padding byte to align the structure to the machine word (e.g. 32 bits). In 32 bits systems, you will read 4 bytes. You can check this printing the `sizeof(struct pixel)`. To read more about structure alignment you could check the Wikipedia article [Data Structure Alignment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_structure_alignment).

Instead a struct, use a `char` array:

```
unsigned char currentPixel[3];
...
fread(currentPixel, 3, 1, oldFile);
printf("%d %d %d", currentPixel[0], currentPixel[1], currentPixel[2]);
```

Also, if you need to read the entire image, create an array of `unsigned char` with size `number of pixels x 3`. The 3 is the number of bytes for the RGB tuple. If the PPM format include some padding at the end of each line, you need to consider this too.

Comment: Shouldnt the line `printf("%c %c %c", currentPixel[0], currentPixel[1], currentPixel[2]);` be `printf("%d %d %d", currentPixel[0], currentPixel[1], currentPixel[2]);`?